# What are these algorithm2e empty warnings?

Tags: texstudio, algorithm2e

I am using the algorithm2e package in my paper and for some reason TexStudio is reporting these 2 warnings from algorithm2e.sty which don't have any message or line number.

When I enable the `Issues and Log` tab to see where these warnings are coming from, they seem to point to the lines containing the asterisks in the following output in the log file.

```
********************************************************
Package `algorithm2e' Release 5.0 -- january 06 2013 --
- algorithm2e-announce@lirmm.fr mailing list for announcement about releases
- algorithm2e-discussion@lirmm.fr mailing list for discussion about package
subscribe by emailing sympa@lirmm.fr with 'subscribe <list> <firstname name>'
- Author: Christophe Fiorio (cfiorio@um2.fr)
********************************************************
```

I don't know if there is an actual warning somewhere or whether it is just TexStudio misinterpreting these.

Are these actually warnings coming from somewhere else? Or is this just something TexStudio is misinterpreting?

Comment: It's just a message advertising the package. I find it annoying, too. Unfortunately it can't be silenced without modifying the package.

Comment: Cheers... submitting a paper and didn't want to have any 'real' warnings!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The message is due to these lines in `algorithm2e.sty`:

```
1214 %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% Main Part %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
1215 %
1216 \newcommand{\algocf@name}{algorithm2e}%
1217 \newcommand{\algocf@date}{january 06 2013}%
1218 \newcommand{\algocf@version}{Release 5.0}%
1219 \newcommand{\algocf@id}{\algocf@version\space -- \algocf@date\space --}%
1220 \typeout{********************************************************^^JPackage `\algocf@name'\space\algocf@id^^J%
1221          - algorithm2e-announce@lirmm.fr  mailing list for announcement about releases^^J%
1222          - algorithm2e-discussion@lirmm.fr mailing list for discussion about package^^J%
1223          subscribe by emailing sympa@lirmm.fr with 'subscribe <list> <firstname name>'^^J%
1224          - Author: Christophe Fiorio (cfiorio@um2.fr)^^J********************************************************}%
```

Unfortunately it is impossible to remove the message without changing the package code or doing nasty tricks such as

```
\let\latextypeout\typeout\def\typeout#1{}
\usepackage{algorithm2e}
\let\typeout\latextypeout
```

which I wouldn't recommend.

The code should use `\PackageInfo` instead:

```
\PackageInfo{algorithm2e}{%
  ********************************************************\MessageBreak
  Package `\algocf@name'\space\algocf@id\MessageBreak
  - algorithm2e-announce@lirmm.fr  mailing list for announcement about releases\MessageBreak
  - algorithm2e-discussion@lirmm.fr mailing list for discussion about package\MessageBreak
  subscribe by emailing sympa@lirmm.fr with 'subscribe <list> <firstname name>'\MessageBreak
  - Author: Christophe Fiorio (cfiorio@um2.fr)\MessageBreak
  ********************************************************%
}
```

This would write the information only in the log file instead of also in the terminal output, which seems to confuse the parser by TeXStudio.